# jquery datatable not pagination and length is not working working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am trying to displaying 10 rows in my DataTable, but it is displaying all the rows. How can I do it? Data is coming from

```
API.$(document).ready(function contractsDatatable() {
    $('#newsDataTable').DataTable({"dom":'<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">'
        });
    });
```

Please find code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rameshbogandla/tnf5s4j3/). You can see it [live](http://52.77.27.178/page/admin#news-Page).

Comment: Your live throws a 404 error

Comment: There are lots of missing functions in your jsFiddle and your live example throws 404 error. Check your console for JS errors, most likely it is the reason jQuery DataTables is not working.